# not able to write to a file from windows service on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: c#

I have a windows service which is writing to a file1.txt and windows service also refers to a dll. the dll also writes to a file2.txt. this works fine on when windows service deployed on my local machine.

On deploying the same code on windows server 2008 r2, i see only windows service writing to file1.txt and dll is not writing to file2.txt.

do need to do any seeting or i am missingany permission setting so that refered dll also writes to file on windows server 2008 r2.

Comment: Do you know what's in that DLL?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are the files on the machines on which the service runs, or a common network location? If the former, do the required directories exist beforehand, if not, does the code create them (you may need to ILDASM the .dll)?

Comment: dll is also simple code. actually i dont want to write from service direcltly so move code for writing into file to dll.

Comment: I have to assume the files are written out to different target directories according to your issue...thus ensure the account which the windows service is running under have write permissions to both directories. Otherwise there is a coding problem in your dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which user runs the service. You can do this in two flavors:

1) Open services, right click, properties, logon tab or
2) Find in Task Manager the by process name.

Check if his users (who runs the server) has rights to read/write in the directory.

Probably, in your machine you have rights and on the server, the user who runs the server don't.

Usually the default "SYSTEM" account doesn't have rights to write anywhere.